# Filter HTML Table Values with Dropdown Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am new to coding and have had trouble finding the answer to this question.  I think my lack of industry vocabulary is limiting my ability to properly search for the solution.. I've searched for two days.

I have a simple HTML table displaying data from my firebase database.  The table looks something like this:

```
Date       Google   Yelp   Bing
-----------------------------------
Mar 2015     1       3      2
Feb 2015     4       0      2
Jan 2015     0       6      1
```

The above table is representative of where our medical practice receives its patients each month.  We are an office of four doctors.

QUESTION: I'd like to create a dropdown at the top of the table with a list of each doc's name.  When I choose the doctor, the table updates automatically with only the stats for that doctor.

How do I solve this?  How do I filter my data?  I'd be super happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

LIMITATIONS: I am learning  HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, and JQUERY and would like to limit my answer using only those languages.

FIREBASE DATABASE: Below is a snippet of the firebase export... notice how each patient is entered into the db as a unique object (ie. "-JlItUSK...").

Then what I do is query the db like this: If the date is march 2015, and the channel is 'Internet', display it in this table cell.

But when I showed this amazing referral tracker to the doctors, their immediate response was: "can I filter by my name?" and "what if I only want to see the female patients - can I filter by gender?"

So, to reiterate my question: how do I create a dropdown that will re-query the database and show the new data based upon the doctor's filter choice?

```
{
  "entries" : {
    "-JlItUSK9n-GD70XAyGz" : {
      "age" : "22",
      "channel" : "null",
      "country" : "USA",
      "date" : "2010-02-26",
      "doctor" : "bh",
      "gender" : "female",
      "initials" : "OW",
      "source" : "Insurance",
      "zip" : "90047"
    },
    "-JlIy5378hYrzPpIw0Ll" : {
      "age" : "12",
      "channel" : "Google",
      "country" : "USA",
      "date" : "2014-05-26",
      "doctor" : "lc",
      "gender" : "male",
      "initials" : "FN",
      "source" : "Internet",
      "zip" : "90029"
    },
    "-JlIzkfSxx9XdVzC74x7" : {
      "age" : "12",
      "channel" : "Bing",
      "country" : "USA",
      "date" : "2011-11-26",
      "doctor" : "bh",
      "gender" : "male",
      "initials" : "SI",
      "source" : "Internet",
      "zip" : "90021"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at datatables - it's a JQuery plug-in - then something like this: https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/ - there are many ways to do this but this is a good start and no point re-inventing wheels

Comment: What have you done so far for the implementation? Any code?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney that looks like a great resource.  reviewing it now.  thanks for the immediate reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited, due to new code and data from OP:

I've made a small example of how you could filter the data, with requerying the database. I only used two of your tables, so you'll have to add the filter mechanic to the rest of your code.

I used this to filter by `doctor` (in the change event of a select):

```
fbEntries.orderByChild("doctor").equalTo(myFilterVariable).on("value", function (snapshot) {
    var fbobj = snapshot.val();
    parseMyData(fbobj); //I placed your old code in this new function
});
```

A few things regarding your code (not bad at all for a a beginner!):

You use a lot of static code and quite messy iterations to manipulate the DOM. I followed your structure as much as I could, but also had to create a few functions, move some code and reorder it in some places. I hope you can find your way around.

I also had to fix some html issues. All your dynamic html was created in "thead", and I needed to be able to remove (reinitialize) the table rows, so I added tbody and a few other things.

Id's are supposed to be unique! You have the table id `monthly-by-doc` on several tables (there are more examples). Make sure that id's are unique for the entire page. I fixed this in my example.

You can see and test the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/9bqdf121/2/

Comment: thanks for the immediate response.  Much appreciated.  In your example, you are showing and hiding data based on the dropdown selection.

Comment: I updated my question after reading everyone's comments.  I hope this clarifies.  Can you take a look and let me know if this is helpful?  Thank you @mackan

Comment: @BenjaminHoffman Great that you updated with some example data. Can you also provide how your code looks when you create the table? I'd like to use the same method of grouping data in to "periods" and adding them up as "totals", so you don't end up with two completely different sets of code.

Comment: yeah definitely... let me warn you, this is my first web project, ever. This is the equivalent of a child learning to crawl. I am definitely open to any feedback / advice you'd like to offer of course, but when you review this code you might think WTF is this kid doing. hahah  Without further ado: https://github.com/benjaminhoffman/referral-tracker

Comment: see the following directory: assets > js > chart.js  &   app > chart.html

Comment: awesome!  thank you for everything.  much appreciated.  wish i could +1 but don't have enough points :(

Comment: @BenjaminHoffman Glad it worked. You can accept my answer as "answer" (by clicking the checkmark). that will be the "same" as +1 :)